# Refer back to old iterator value in click() function for javascript/jQuery (closure question)

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I'm trying to get the "click()" function to display the value of `'i'` at the time I passed in the function.  But its referring back to the value of `'i'` after it finished.  I'm drawing a blank on how to get the function to refer to the value of `'i'` when I first passed the function in.

```
for( var i=0; i<10; i++){
 var ts = $('#<span></span>').clone().click(function(){
  alert(i);
 });
}
```

**NOTE:**

The `'#'` shouldn't be there, neither should the `'.clone()'`

Comment: +1 for correctly inferring the problem.

Comment: Consider rolling the question back to the original. The answers given make less sense when you change the question. :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  (function(j) {
    var ts = $('<span></span>').click(function(){
        alert(j);
    });
  })(i);
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ruHjJ/). Though, your creation is a bit off, I'm not sure why you'd want to create a new element just to clone it, and there's an extra `#` in there....I removed both of these above, but it doesn't affect the solution of an inner function.

Comment: This is the correct answer; wrapping the event handler in an anonymous function and passing it i produces the desired closure.

Comment: Hey Nick, I thought I read somewhere that jQuery saves an element once you make it so you have to clone it if you want a new one.  I'm hazy even on the memory though, so thats probably wrong.

Comment: @DutrowLLC - It does, if the HTML string used to create it is shorter than 512 bytes, then the document fragment it creates is cached, but *that* is cloned already (for speed) so you don't need ti do it yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the body of the loop to a separate function that takes `i` as a parameter.

You can use a normal function, like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    makeCopy(i);
}

function makeCopy(i) { 
    var ts = $('#<span></span>').clone().click(function(){
        alert(i);
    });
}
```

You can also use an inline method, like this: (beware confusing syntax)

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    (function(i) { //Note i parameter
        var ts = $('#<span></span>').clone().click(function(){
            alert(i);
        });
        ...
    })(i);         //Note i parameter
}
```

Comment: Your second approach will alert `10` in all cases.

Comment: @SLaks - Because `i` still refers to the same outer variable, you can test it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ruHjJ/1/ You have to pass `i` into the function to get a copy.

Comment: For clarity of example I'd rename the variable inside the function, but as it is it'll work :)

Comment: Technically it would have alerted `undefined`, as `i` was used inside and outside.